# When calling a getMethod on a Subclass object with the same var name as parent class which variable does it return?

Tags: java, inheritance

You have two classes A and B:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        B objB = new B();
        objB.doSomething(); 

// Output: Im in class B
//10
    }
}

class A{
    private int num= 10;

    public int getNum(){
        return num;
    }


}

class B extends A{
    private int num= 5;

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Im in class B");
        System.out.println(getNum());
    }
}
```

What happends in memory and why is it printing the int 10 instead of 5 ? I understand that the objB has both the class A num, aswell as Class B num. But why if B inherits method getNum from A.

Shouldn't the return, return the value of num of class B ? as it is called upon the object created from class B ?

Comment: Instance fields don't get "overridden".

Comment: Okay I understand but why when calling getNum does it return the value of A.num instead of B.num ? I can’t picture this in my head.

Comment: there are two separate variables and class A only knows of one that always has value 10.